# Jquery .getJson() unexpected token :

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, web-services

When I tried to access the below URL:

### http://dhclinicappv2stg.item-soft.co.il/LinkCareAppService.svc/json/GetFinalReportToAccount?AccountId=123

I get a JSON service response. I'm trying to read this response via Jquery, like so :

```js
   (function()
      {
         var serviceAPI = "http://dhclinicappv2stg.item-soft.co.il/LinkCareAppService.svc/json/GetFinalReportToAccount?AccountId=?";
         $.getJSON( serviceAPI,
        {
          AccountId: "123"
         })
         .done(function( data )
         {
           alert(data);
         });
        })();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>jQuery.getJSON attempt</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body>
 
    <div id="data"></div> <!-- in the future, I will add the data to this div -->
 
    <script>
   
      </script>
 
      </body>
    </html>
```

Yet I get a blank page, with no alerts. The console log reads the error in the title.

#### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The url, you gave, returns xml and not json.

Comment: @Sirko how can I refer to it then?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder These are the parameters. Nosession is a parameter called "Message", and true is a parameter called "Error". in the console, I can see them paired as JSON

Comment: @A.Abramov: I just looked at the source of what's sent back. Sirko's right, it's XML, not JSON.

Comment: @A.Abramov, your service url is wrong for getJSON method. check out my answer !

Comment: @A.Abramov: That service you're calling **does** allow access via CORS, see Venkatraman's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with Service. Only mistake with your service URL remove `?AccountId=?` due to this service call triggered as like below.

`/GetFinalReportToAccount?AccountId=jQuery21101485728188417852_1451208967751&AccountId=123&_=1451208967752`

Try the below working snippet where parameter removed in URL for `getJSON` Method.

```js
(function() {
   var serviceAPI = "http://dhclinicappv2stg.item-soft.co.il/LinkCareAppService.svc/json/GetFinalReportToAccount";
   $.getJSON(serviceAPI, {
           AccountId: "123"
       })
       .done(function(data) {

          $('#data').text(JSON.stringify(data));
       });
})();
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
             <meta charset="utf-8">
             <title>jQuery.getJSON attempt</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          </head>
        <body>
     
        <div id="data"></div> <!-- in the future, I will add the data to this div -->
     
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Also important to note that it returns XML, not JSON. And for lurkers, this only works because the endpoint supports CORS (apparently from any origin).